# Android Emulator Error - Failed to open ..../joshuaduong/..../qemu.conf, err: 2

Tags: android, android-studio

When I executed the following command.

`emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28_86 -wipe-data -no-boot-anim`

I got the following error message.

`Failed to open /usr/local/google/home/joshuaduong/emu/master/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2`

The emulator starts and works fine. However, I am not comfortable receiving an error message. Moreover, I have no idea who "joshuaduong" is. I searched for this path in Android Studio files. Interestingly (or scary) enough, I found it in the following dll file:

`C:\Users\<MyUserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\glib-2-vs11.dll`

and in 8 exe files:

`C:\Users\<MyUserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system<something>.exe`

Why would "joshuaduong" be in dll and exe files! Have these files been compromised? Avast Free Antivirus could not find anything wrong with them. What package/library should I re-install to get a fresh copy of these files. The ones I got have a timestamp of 12/12/2019. I think I downloaded some updates on that date.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly no expert, but it looks like the Google engineer left the references of their library dependencies and bundled it all up by accident.

I certainly don't believe it's malicious. I'm running the Stable channel and I see it too when I run the emulator through console. I can't get my hands on the Canary channel right now, but it's possible this might've been fixed there since they updated the emulator yesterday.

Comment: Joshua is listed on LinkedIn as a Google Developer. I had to do a complete OS reboot to get past this.